# Converting an untyped AST for a simple typed language into a GADT

Tags: haskell, gadt

I have an ADT representing the AST for a simple language:

```
data UTerm = UTrue
      | UFalse
      | UIf UTerm UTerm UTerm
      | UZero
      | USucc UTerm
      | UIsZero UTerm
```

This data structure can represent invalid terms that don't follow the type
rules of the language, like `UIsZero UFalse`, so I'd like to use a GADT that
enforces well-typedness:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data TTerm a where
  TTrue :: TTerm Bool
  TFalse :: TTerm Bool
  TIf :: TTerm Bool -> TTerm a -> TTerm a -> TTerm a
  TZero :: TTerm Int
  TSucc :: TTerm Int -> TTerm Int
  TIsZero :: TTerm Int -> TTerm Bool
```

My problem is to type check a UTerm and convert it into a TTerm. My first
thought was `UTerm -> Maybe (TTerm a)`, but this of course doesn't work because
it's not valid for all `a`s. I don't even know what the type would be, because
we don't know if `a` is going to be Int or Bool. Then I thought I could write a
different type checking function for each of the possible values of `a`:

```
import Control.Applicative

typecheckbool :: UTerm -> Maybe (TTerm Bool)
typecheckbool UTrue = Just TTrue
typecheckbool UFalse = Just TFalse
typecheckbool (UIsZero a) = TIsZero <$> typecheckint a
typecheckbool _ = Nothing

typecheckint :: UTerm -> Maybe (TTerm Int)
typecheckint UZero = Just TZero
typecheckint (USucc a) = TSucc <$> typecheckint a
typecheckint (UIf a b c) = TIf <$> typecheckbool a <*> typecheckint b <*> typecheckint c
typecheckint UTrue = Nothing
typecheckint UFalse = Nothing
typecheckint (UIsZero _) = Nothing
```

This works for some cases, for a subset of the language where TIf requires its
consequent and alternative are Ints (But `TIf TTrue TFalse TTrue` is actually
totally valid), and where we know the target type of the expression we're
typing.

What's the right way to convert from a UTerm to a TTerm?

Comment: By the way, you could certainly add a `typecheckbool (UIf a b c)` case to address the "But `TIf TTrue TFalse TTrue` is actually totally valid" concern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard technique is to define an existential type:

```
data ETerm_ where
    ETerm_ :: TTerm a -> ETerm
```

In this case, you may also want some term-level evidence of which type you have; e.g.

```
data Type a where
    TInt :: Type Int
    TBool :: Type Bool
```

then the real `ETerm` would look like this:

```
data ETerm where
    ETerm :: Type a -> TTerm a -> ETerm
```

The interesting case of type checking is then something like

```
typeCheck (UIf ucond ut uf) = do
    ETerm TBool tcond <- typeCheck ucond
    ETerm tyt tt <- typeCheck ut
    ETerm tyf tf <- typeCheck uf
    case (tyt, tyf) of
        (TBool, TBool) -> return (ETerm TBool (TIf tcond tt tf))
        (TInt , TInt ) -> return (ETerm TInt  (TIf tcond tt tf))
        _ -> fail "branches have different types"
```

Comment: Could this still be done if the term/type languages contained variables? Could the `Type` datatype represent such a language?

Comment: @user2407038 It is certainly possible to define a language with a more expressive type system than Haskell's; then you will not be able to use Haskell's type-checker to check that terms in that language are type-correct. However, for the most part, if your language's type system is less expressive than Haskell's, then you can convince Haskell to check your terms for you -- though of course with more effort the more exciting your system is.

Answer (score 5):

As a minor complement of @DanielWagner's answer, you might want to factorize type equality checks such as

```
...
case (tyt, tyf) of
        (TBool, TBool) -> return (ETerm TBool (TIf tcond tt tf))
        (TInt , TInt ) -> return (ETerm TInt  (TIf tcond tt tf))
        _ -> fail "branches have different types"
```

One way to do that is using equality witnesses:

```
import Data.Type.Equality

typeEq :: Type a -> Type b -> Maybe (a :~: b)
typeEq TInt  TInt  = Just Refl
typeEq TBool TBool = Just Refl
typeEq _     _     = Nothing

typeCheck :: UTerm -> Maybe ETerm
typeCheck (UIf ucond ut uf) = do
    ETerm TBool tcond <- typeCheck ucond
    ETerm tyt tt <- typeCheck ut
    ETerm tyf tf <- typeCheck uf
    case typeEq tyt tyf of
        Just Refl -> return (ETerm tyt (TIf tcond tt tf))
        _         -> fail "branches have different types"
```

This factorization is convenient if you need to check type equality in multiple parts of your type checking routine. It also allows for extending the language with pair types like `(t1,t2)`, which require a structural recursive approach to check type equality.

One might even write a full decider for type equality

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
typeEq2 :: Type a -> Type b -> Either (a :~: b) ((a :~:b) -> Void)
typeEq2 TInt  TInt  = Left Refl
typeEq2 TInt  TBool = Right (\eq -> case eq of)
typeEq2 TBool TBool = Left Refl
typeEq2 TBool TInt  = Right (\eq -> case eq of)
```

but this, I guess, will probably not be needed unless you are trying to model quite advanced types (e.g. GADTs).

The code above uses and empty case to examine all the possible values `eq` can have. Since it has type e.g. `Int :~: Bool`, and there are no constructors matching with that type, we are left with no possible values for `eq` and so no case branch is needed. This will *not* trigger an exhaustiveness warning, since there are indeed no cases left unhandled (OT: I wish these warnings to be actual errors).

Instead of using `EmptyCase` you can also use something like `case eq of _ -> undefined`, but using bottoms in proof terms like the above one is fishy.

Comment: This is helpful, especially if there's more than 2 types, thanks. Why doesn't pattern matching in the do block (http://lpaste.net/133738) work but a case statement does?

Comment: `Just Refl <- ...` looks wrong, the `Just` was already removed (loosely speaking) by the `<-` desugaring. Try `Refl <- ...` instead. (I'm not completely sure how that interacts with GADTs, though.)

Comment: Can you give me a hint about how to prove `a :~: b) -> Void`?