# In Haskell, how to parse an untyped AST to a typed one based on a GADT?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, typechecking, applicative, gadt

I'm writing a domain-specific language in Haskell, and have settled on
a design with two ASTs: an initial untyped one that represents syntax and
a final typed one that represents everything. I'm writing the final one as
a GADT to get better typechecking.

I think it's *almost* working, but I'm having trouble writing a function that
converts initial -> final (checks the types, plus some other things not shown,
like all references correspond to a variable).

Here's a simplified example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving #-}

module Main where

-- untyped initial AST

data Untyped
  = UNum Int
  | UStr String
  | UAdd Untyped Untyped
  deriving (Show, Eq)

-- typed final AST

data Typed a where
  TNum :: Int    -> Typed Int
  TStr :: String -> Typed String
  TAdd :: Typed Int -> Typed Int -> Typed Int

deriving instance Eq   (Typed a)
deriving instance Show (Typed a)

-- wrapper that allows working with a `Typed a` for any `a`
data TypedExpr where
  TypedExpr :: Typed a -> TypedExpr
```

And this is my attempt at the `check` function. The base cases are simple:

```
check :: Untyped -> Either String TypedExpr
check (UNum n) = Right $ TypedExpr $ TNum n
check (UStr s) = Right $ TypedExpr $ TStr s
-- check (Uadd e1 e2) = ???
```

But how do I add `Add`? It can recursively evaluate the sub-expressions to
values of type `Either String (TypedExpr (Typed a))`, but I haven't managed to
unwrap those, check that the types line up (both `a`s should be `Int`s), and
re-wrap afterward. I planned to do it all with big pattern matches, but GHC
doesn't approve:

```
My brain just exploded
  I can't handle pattern bindings for existential or GADT data constructors.
  Instead, use a case-expression, or do-notation, to unpack the constructor.
```

That's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531566/odd-ghc-error-message-my-brain-just-exploded), but I didn't understand the explanation. It seems
I don't want pattern matching.

Update: I must have messed something else up without noticing. Pattern matching works, as shown by Nikita.

So I fiddled around trying to force things into
the right shape, but haven't gotten anything substantial yet. If these were
just `Either String SomeValue` I would want to use applicatives, right? Is it
possible to add another level of unwrapping + type checking to them? I suspect [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30565412/429898) is close to what I want since the question is very similar, but again I don't understand it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944498/how-to-parse-string-into-gadt) may also be related.

Update: [That first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30565412/429898) is just what I wanted after all. But I couldn't see how until chi wrote the intermediate version below without the extra `Type` type. Here's a working solution. The trick was to tag `TypedExpr`s with a new type representing just the *return* type (`a`) of a `Typed a`:

```
data Returns a where
  RNum :: Returns Int
  RStr :: Returns String

-- extend TypedExpr to include the return type
data TypedExpr2 where
  TypedExpr2 :: Returns a -> Typed a -> TypedExpr2
```

That way `check` doesn't have to know whether each subexpression is a raw
`TNum` or a function (like `Add`) that returns a `TNum`:

```
check :: Untyped -> Either String TypedExpr2
check (UNum n) = Right $ TypedExpr2 RNum (TNum n)
check (UStr s) = Right $ TypedExpr2 RStr (TStr s)
check (UAdd u1 u2) = do
  -- typecheck subexpressions, then unwrap by pattern matching
  TypedExpr2 r1 t1 <- check u1
  TypedExpr2 r2 t2 <- check u2
  -- check the tags to find out their return types
  case (r1, r2) of
    -- if correct, create an overall expression tagged with its return type
    (RNum, RNum) -> return $ TypedExpr2 RNum $ TAdd t1 t2
    _ -> Left "type error"
```

GHC is smart enough to know that the two `a`s in any `TypedExpr2` must match,
so it catches you if you attempt to use the wrong overall return type at the
end. Wonderful!

Comment: How about something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27838550/477476)? See https://gergo.erdi.hu/blog/2015-02-05-typed_embedding_of_stlc_into_haskell/ for an extended explanation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Technically it *is* doable, but it's quite inconvenient: you have to "dig" until the GADT constructor is found.

```
check :: Untyped -> Either String TypedExpr
check (UNum n) = return $ TypedExpr $ TNum n
check (UStr s) = return $ TypedExpr $ TStr s
check (UAdd t1 t2) = do
    t1 <- check t1
    t2 <- check t2
    case (t1, t2) of
      (TypedExpr (TNum x)     , TypedExpr (TNum y))
         -> return $ TypedExpr $ TAdd (TNum x    ) (TNum y)
      (TypedExpr (TAdd x1 x2) , TypedExpr (TNum y))
         -> return $ TypedExpr $ TAdd (TAdd x1 x2) (TNum y)
      (TypedExpr (TNum x)     , TypedExpr (TAdd y1 y2))
         -> return $ TypedExpr $ TAdd (TNum x    ) (TAdd y1 y2)
      (TypedExpr (TAdd x1 x2) , TypedExpr (TAdd y1 y2))
         -> return $ TypedExpr $ TAdd (TAdd x1 x2) (TAdd y1 y2)
      _ -> Left "type error"
```

I would look for alternatives. The above approach suffers from combinatorial explosion when the number of constructors is large.

Comment: What do you think of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30565412/429898)? It adds a separate `Type` tag to the `TypedExpr`s (which it calls `ETerm`s), then checks the tag rather than the constructor used. It seems you only have to define a `Type` for each possible *return* type in the DSL that way. For example `Add` and `TNum` could both be tagged with `Type ReturnsNum` (should have picked different names). It still explodes with the number of basic types, but I could probably keep that to just numbers, strings, booleans, and sets of those.

Comment: @Jeff I like that approach.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to use a "plain" representation of your universe of types (with an interpretation type function), and then store a `Sing`leton reification of your existential type in `TypedExpr`, i.e. something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies #-}

data Type = TInt | TString

type family InterpT (a :: Type) where
  InterpT TInt = Int
  InterpT TString = String

-- plus the usual singletons stuff
-- ...

-- and finally
data Typed (a :: Type) where ...

data TypedExpr where
  TypedExpr :: Sing a -> Typed a -> TypedExpr
```

This way, you can do something like

```
check (UAdd e1 e2) = do
  TypedExpr t1 e1' <- check e1
  TypedExpr t2 e2' <- check e2
  case testEquality t1 t2 of
    Just Refl -> ... use e1' and e2' here, you know they have the same Type
    Nothing -> Left ...
```

Find a fully fleshed-out example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27838550/477476).

Answer (score 0):

Your exact question is easily answerable with the following solution:

```
check (UAdd (UNum a) (UNum b)) = Right $ TypedExpr $ TAdd (TNum a) (TNum b)
```

However there's quite a few indications of a design maze there.

Do you realize that once you put something into `TypedExpr` you lose all the information about the `a` type? This renders your `check` function quite pointless.

I understand that you do so because it's the only way you can unify the types of your GADT, and otherwise you can't implement the `check` function. But actually it just proves that you're modeling things wrong and that GADT might be inappropriate for your use case.

I don't understand why the `UAdd` constructor is over `Untyped` values, instead of `Int`, and I don't understand what made you go with this multi-stage AST strategy.

I could go on, but I'll break here and just recommend you to redesign your model.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I thought that was the first thing I tried (causing the "my brain exploded" error), but must have accidentally changed something else at the same time. Guess the whole question was a little pointless.

What do you mean by lose all information though? You can get the values back, and types aren't needed anymore because the GADT gaurantees they line up.

EDIT: Oh, the reason it's not over `Int`s is the language also involves set operations and I'm using `+` for unions.

Comment: Oh nevermind I think I get it. Value-level type tags are needed to know how you can combine the GADTs later when you have more than one. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564967/converting-an-untyped-ast-for-a-simple-typed-language-into-a-gadt) seems like it would work, but you're right it's a little convoluted.